# Write a program, which reads an Integer. Output another integer where the even digits are retained and odd digits are decremented by 1,

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, integer, double

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int num, i = 0, new_num = 0, u;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while (num > 0) {
        u = num % 10;
        if (u % 2 == 0)
            u = u;
        if (u % 2 == 1)
            u = u - 1;
        new_num = new_num + u * pow(10, i);
        num = num / 10;
        i++;
    }
    printf("The new number is: %d", new_num);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I am doing this in gcc(VS Code), for 2-digit number everything is ok. But for digits more than three I am getting a error. Like Input=`23145` Output=`22043`. But I was expecting output=`22044`.

Also, if I run the same code in DevC/C++, there is no error.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: What is in your tasks.json? You do not build it the same way in the two environments. devc also use gcc.

Comment: In some implementations, the `pow` function isn't exact, even if the exponent is an integer. For powers of 10, it might be better to make `i` that power, start with `i = 1` and then instead of incrementing, multiply `i = i * 10`. This will also get rid of `<math.h>`.

Comment: When I run your code on Ubuntu in WSL, I get output `22044` as expected. What environment do you use?

Comment: @Gerhardh I am on windows 10. I ran the code on VS Code and Dev-C/C++ separately. On VS code, I got the error.

Comment: This sound like a duplicate of another question dealing with `pow` from a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 3):

Your program produces the expected output on my system: `22044` for `23145`, but this might depend on the implementation of the `pow` function.

The reason you get a different output is probably a side effect of a precision issue with the `pow()` function in your C library: if `pow(x, y)` is implemented as `exp(y * log(x))`, the result for integral values of `x` and `y` could be very close but inferior to the actual integral value, causing the conversion to `int` to produce the previous integer. Some C library authors make a special case of integral arguments to avoid this problem, but it is highly recommended to avoid floating point functions for integer arithmetics to prevent such tricky issues.

I would advise some more changes in your code:

- test the return value of `scanf()`.
- remove the `if (u % 2 == 0) u = u;` part, it has no effect.
- in any case, there should be an `else` clause to not use the result of the previous case when testing for odd digits.
- do not use the floating point function `pow()`: just keep a multiplier variable and update it in the loop.
- the program does not handle negative numbers.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num, new_num = 0, pow10 = 1;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
        return 1;
    while (num != 0) {
        int digit = num % 10;
        /* decrement odd digits absolute value */
        digit -= digit % 2;
        new_num = new_num + digit * pow10;
        pow10 = pow10 * 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    printf("The new number is: %d\n", new_num);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `digit -= digit % 2;` will decrement positive odd digits and actually increment negative odd digits, which effectively always decrements the absolute value of odd digits.  This way both positive values and negative values are handled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is using the function `pow` that returns a double value.

If you are dealing with integers then it is better to avoid using functions that return doubles due to a possible truncation then a double is converted to an integer.

Also pay attention to that the user can enter a negative number. Your program allows to do that. In this case your program also will produce an incorrect result.

I would write the program the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    while (1)
    {
        const int Base = 10;
        int num;

        printf( "Enter a number (0 - exit): " );

        if (scanf( "%d", &num ) != 1 || num == 0) break;

        int new_num = 0;
        
        for (int tmp = num, multiplier = 1; tmp != 0; tmp /= Base)
        {
            int digit = tmp % Base;

            if (digit % 2 != 0)
            {
                digit += ( digit < 0 ? 1 : -1 );
            }
            new_num = new_num + multiplier * digit;
            multiplier *= Base;
        }

        printf( "The original number is %d and the new number is: %d\n", 
                num, new_num );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Enter a number (0 - exit): -123456789
The original number is -123456789 and the new number is: -22446688

Enter a number (0 - exit): 123456789
The original number is 123456789 and the new number is: 22446688

Enter a number (0 - exit): 0
```

If even for negative digits to add -1 then you should substitute this if statement

```
if (digit % 2 != 0)
{
    digit += ( digit < 0 ? 1 : -1 );
}
```

for this one

```
if (digit % 2 != 0)
{
    digit = ( digit -1 ) % Base;
}
```

In this case the program output might look like

```
Enter a number (0 - exit): -123456789
The original number is -123456789 and the new number is: -224466880

Enter a number (0 - exit): 123456789
The original number is 123456789 and the new number is: 22446688

Enter a number (0 - exit): 0
```

That is in this case the new value for the negative value `-123456789` will be `-224466880`.

Answer (score 2):

In my instance of Visual Studio Code, for an input 23145, I indeed find 22044 as an output.

I guess the divergence comes with the cast of `pow(10,i)`. Pow function in C returns a double which is not what you really want here. I strongly advice to not use the `pow` function for integer arithmetic.

A solution could be :

```
uint16_t i = 0u;
uint16_t current_digit = 0u, decimal_digit = 1u;

uint16_t new_number = 0u;
uint16_t number = 23145u;

while(number > 0u) {
    current_digit = number % 10;

    if (current_digit % 2) {
        current_digit = current_digit - 1;
    }
    new_number = new_number + current_digit * decimal_digit;
    decimal_digit *= 10u;
    number /= 10;
    i++;
}
printf("The new number is: %d", new_number);
```